# How can I console.log() a Blob object?

Tags: javascript, blob, console.log

I have a Blob object I want to inspect by logging its value. All I can see are `type` and `size` properties. Is there a way to do this?

[image: console.logging a blob shows this]

Comment: What browser are you using?

Comment: I'm using Chrome 39 (latest as of now)

Comment: You cannot directly view the data inside a blob object, you have to use something like [FileReader's readDataAs*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader#Methods) methods

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updated for 2023, this can now be done with

```js
await blob.text()
```

(Thanks @Kaiido)

Answer (score 20):

Basic example on using a [FileReader](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader) to look at the content in a blob

```js
var html= ['<a id="anchor">Hello World</a>'];
var myBlob = new Blob(html, { type: 'text/xml'});
var myReader = new FileReader();
myReader.onload = function(event){
    console.log(JSON.stringify(myReader.result));
};
myReader.readAsText(myBlob);
```

Comment: Can be utterly shortened with `await blob.text()` nowadays.

Comment: @Kaiido thanks for that updated answer - I've just posted that and changed the accepted answer.

Answer (score -2):

First of all we should create a function for converting blob to base64:

```js
const blobToBase64 = blob => {
  const reader = new FileReader();
  reader.readAsDataURL(blob);
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    reader.onloadend = () => {
      resolve(reader.result);
    };
  });
};
```

Then we can use this function to use it for `console.log`:

```js
blobToBase64(blobData).then(res => {
  console.log(res); // res is base64 now
  // even you can click on it to see it in a new tab
});
```

Comment: He did not want to see base64.